# Visual Studios Query Issue, Cannot Perform = operation on system.double and system.string?

Tags: c#, sql, query-builder

First of all my apologies if the question seems really simple, I've used Visual Studios in the past but haven't touched it for about 3 years. The situation is, I currently have a database connected to my form created using Visual Studios but I can't figure out how to do the search. Currently the code I have for the search button is:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            data_BindingSource.Filter = "First_name LIKE '" + textBox1.Text + "%' AND Last_Name LIKE '" + textBox2.Text + "%' AND ID = '" + textBox3.Text + "%'";
        }
```

The first name and last name search works fine but I'm running into a error when I'm trying to search for ID as well. I believe this is a data type issue as the data type for ID is dbl while first_name and last_name are strings. How would I do a conversion in order to make the search work? Thanks!

**EDIT:** The revised code below works, but there is a (System.Data.SyntaxErrorException: 'Syntax error: Missing operand after '=' operator.') error that occurs when the ID field is not filled in. If I remove the ID portion then the search works perfectly fine with first name last name even if one of them are left blank. Is this still an issue of data types? Can someone explain what the issue is? Thanks so much!

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            data_BindingSource.Filter = "First_name LIKE '" + textBox1.Text + "%' AND Last_Name LIKE '" + textBox2.Text + "%' AND ID = " + textBox3.Text;
        }
```

Comment: I can see two possible problems. 1) looks like a typo - your use of `%`, and 2) there is the use of quote marks round a number (because quote marks usually imply a string). e.g. `ID = '" + textBox3.Text + "%'"` ...if textbox3 contains `20`, then this will become `ID = '20%'` when the string is resolved. If `ID` is a `double` field then clearly it can never equal `20%` and indeed, as the error says, .NET doesn't even know how to begin to do such a comparison. I suggest changing your code to `ID = " + textBox3.Text`. In my example that would output `ID = 20`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It works when I just enter an ID but if I enter a first name or last name alongside the ID I get a

 System.Data.SyntaxErrorException: 'Syntax error: Missing operand after '=' operator.'

The error also occurs if I just enter a first name or last name without an ID. Would you happen to know what the issue is?

Comment: That seems a bit strange. Have you used the debugger to see what the final Filter value actually looks like? Then you'll see if anything is missing.

Comment: I haven't used the debugger before so my apologies if I'm not looking at the right thing. But from the looks of it textBox1.Text="fname", textBox2.Text="", and textBox3.Text="" I'm not sure if I can, but I could also screenshot if that helps. Thanks so much!

Actually also it seems like things will work if an ID is entered first then followed by first name or last name. However, if a first name or last name is entered without an ID the error occurs.

Comment: Typo in % symbol please check all the syntax properly

Comment: "However, if a first name or last name is entered without an ID the error occurs."...well as you can imagine, that's because it makes the final part of your filter string be `ID = `. Which clearly is nonsense...it's incomplete. So if your fields are optional, you need to write some code to check whether each field is populated or not, before deciding whether to include that field in the filter string. Build the string up gradually, before you pass it to the data source.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what's the reasoning behind this? Is it because of the data type difference? I tried removing the ID portion and both first name and last name search works fine if one or the other or even both of them are left empty. Again, apologies if this is relatively simple, I haven't coded in 2-3 years so the bulk of this was created using youtube videos.